# Preserve Timezone while parsing a string to date in java

Tags: java

While parsing `String` `"Sat Mar  2 09:40:20 PST 2019"`, it is getting converted to IST. How can I preserve the timezone while parsing the string to a date.

Comment: Please include your Java code, without which we can't really help you.

Answer (score 2):

This could be done using standard Java time library and ZonedDateTime class. Take a look at following example how to do it:

```
    String date = "Sat Mar 2 09:40:20 PST 2019";
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
    ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(date,formatter);
    System.out.println(zonedDateTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a Key/Value pair of all global timezones and their GMT offset, then you can reconvert the times from there. Here's a list: https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/tividd/td/TWS/SC32-1274-02/en_US/HTML/SRF_mst273.htm